# Truncate text and wrap it with double quotes using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have some text which needs to be wrapped by double quotes and needs to be truncated by ellipsis if it exceeds two lines. Irrespective of whether the text is truncated or not, it should be wrapped by double quotes.

In my case - in the attached snippet, the line clamp CSS is overriding the ::after CSS.

**Requirement:**

```
"bla bla bla
 bla bla bl..."
```

**My css behavior:** (Ending " is overridden by ...)

```
"bla bla bla
 bla bla bl...
```

```css
.sampleText {
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";
}

.sampleText::before {
  content: open-quote;
}

.sampleText::after {
  content: close-quote;
}

.lineClamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="sampleText lineClamp">
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and Jived fox nymph grabs quick waltz.
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this in CSS only unless you divide the text and the quotes into three parts - head - middle - tail. The issue being that the quotes belong to the text that gets truncated.

Comment: This can be done inCSS. In future you could just alter the ellipsis text to include the closing quote, but currently the only browser that supports this seems to be Firefox so you have to use after pseudo element, which can work if you position it.

Comment: are you aware that the solution you accepted won't work if the text is not truncated?

Comment: I've adjusted the solution btw.

Answer (score 3):

You can use relative positioning to anchor the pseudo-element that will contain your quotes i.e. `position: relative` on the `.sampleText` and then you use `position: absolute` on the pseudo-element after the text.

This seems to do the trick.

**EDIT**

Based on Temani's feedback, I've updated the solution to also cover the case where the text is not truncated and does not take the whole 160px - the closing quote might be too far to the right in this case.

```css
.sampleText {
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";
}

.sampleText::before {
  content: open-quote;
}

.sampleText::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: close-quote;
}

.lineClamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";
}

.content::before {
  content: open-quote;
}

.end-quote {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.end-quote::before {
  content: close-quote;
}

.line-clamp-fixed {
  width: 160px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h3>Solution with fixed width</h3>
  <span class="sampleText lineClamp">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and Jived fox nymph grabs quick waltz.
  </span>
  <hr>
  <span class="sampleText lineClamp">Non truncated text.</span>
  <hr>

  <h3>Solution with flexible width</h3>
  <div class="line-clamp-fixed">
    <span class="content lineClamp">Non truncated text fix.</span>
    <span class="end-quote"></span>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="line-clamp-fixed">
    <span class="content lineClamp">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and Jived fox nymph grabs quick waltz.</span>
    <span class="end-quote"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this will not cover the case of "text non-truncated"

Comment: @TemaniAfif You are right. However, it makes sense since the width is hard coded to be 160px. But, I see your point ... depending on your goals it might be undesirable. I've found another solution using flexbox. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: can you provide that solution? @F.Müller

Comment: @Surya I had already edited the post. So you can checkout the "Solution with flexible width" instead.